# Condition: if value contains multiple strings

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, conditional

I'm not too great at the string builder or lookup fx's.

I'm dealing with folders and want an approval process to go to User A if the folder is named "ABC" or "DEF".

I'm using the condition: if any value equals value and I've set the first value field to "Current Item:Encoded Absolute URL" then the condition to "contains" (equals should work as well if I can figure out the "or" problem) and that's where I lose it. How do I essentially do an or on the last value field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About a quarter of the way down [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/workflow-conditions-quick-reference-sharepoint-2010-workflow-platform) I found the answer. It uses logical or (||) and logical and (&&)

Comment: Nice!  I learned something new today. :)

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just do sequential `if`s?  Set a workflow variable to false, and do sequential `if`s to check for each of the conditions you're looking for. Pseudo-code:

```
shouldGoToUserA = false // set the workflow variable

if Item:Encoded Absolute URL contains "ABC"
    shouldGoToUserA = true

if Item:Encoded Absolute URL contains "DEF"
    shouldGoToUserA = true

if shouldGoToUserA
    // do your stuff to go to user A
```

Comment: I could. But there are multiple groups of folders some with 5+ folders that should be approved by User A. If I can do an "or" I limit the if-else conditions to about 14, but if I expand each folder in a sequential if then I'd be pushing 45+ if-else conditions. I just wanted to keep the approval task to 1 if condition that encompassed all folders they need to approve.